# TypeScript definition for builtin 'net' NodeJS types?

Tags: node.js, typescript, package

I am trying to write a TCP client application, and for that the builtin 'net' package seems to do the job. However, I am not able to find the TypeScript definitions for the package.

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Since it is built into NodeJs, I am almost sure it exists, but it cannot find any information about it anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are available in the official [typings for node](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts#L1935). Install it with `npm install @types/node --save-dev` and you can import it in your TypeScript code using: `import * as net from "net";`